# Approximation of roots using Series

Tags: polynomials, series-expansion, approximation

I am solving a fifth degree polynomial using Series. My equation looks like

```
    I p^5 + 2 p^4 y wo + x^2 y z^2 wo^5 - 2 p^2 y wo (x^2 wo^2 + z^2 wo^2 + 4 wo^2) - 
  I p^3 (x^2 wo^2 + y^2 wo^2 + 2 z^2 wo^2 + 4 wo^2) + I p (z^4 wo^4 + x^2 wo^2 (y^2 wo^2 + z^2 wo^2) + 4 y^2 wo^2 wo^2) ==
  0
```

Using Solve I obtain the roots using Root

```
    {{p -> Root[
    wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 1]}, {p -> 
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 2]}, {p -> 
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 3]}, {p -> 
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 4]}, {p -> 
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 5]}}
```

Now I make approximation based on $1 \gg z \gg x \gg y$ using Series, that is

```
     Assuming[wo \[Element] Reals && 
  wo > 0, 
 Normal[Series[
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 1], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 2}]]];

Assuming[wo \[Element] Reals && 
  wo > 0, 
 Normal[Series[
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 2}]]]

Assuming[wo \[Element] Reals && 
  wo > 0, 
 Normal[Series[
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 3], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 2}]]]

Assuming[wo \[Element] Reals && 
  wo > 0, 
 Normal[Series[
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 4], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 2}]]]

Assuming[wo \[Element] Reals && 
  wo > 0, 
 Normal[Series[
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 5], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 2}]]]
```

The outputs that I get are

```
    -2 wo - (wo z^2)/2 + 1/4 I wo y z^2;
     -((wo z^2)/2) + y (I wo - 1/4 I wo z^2);
     (I wo x^2 y)/z^2;
     (wo z^2)/2 + y (I wo - 1/4 I wo z^2);
     2 wo + (wo z^2)/2 + 1/4 I wo y z^2;
```

respectively. However, when I change the sequence of the series that is,

```
    Assuming[wo \[Element] Reals && 
  wo > 0, 
 Normal[Series[
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 1], {z, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]]];
Assuming[wo \[Element] Reals && 
  wo > 0, 
 Normal[Series[
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 2], {z, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]]];

Assuming[wo \[Element] Reals && 
  wo > 0, 
 Normal[Series[
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 3], {z, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]]];

Assuming[wo \[Element] Reals && 
  wo > 0, 
 Normal[Series[
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &, 4], {z, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]]];

Assuming[wo \[Element] Reals && 
  wo > 0, 
 Normal[Series[
   Root[wo^5 x^2 y z^2 + 4 I wo^4 y^2 #1 + I wo^4 x^2 y^2 #1 + 
      I wo^4 x^2 z^2 #1 + I wo^4 z^4 #1 - 8 wo^3 y #1^2 - 
      2 wo^3 x^2 y #1^2 - 2 wo^3 y z^2 #1^2 - 4 I wo^2 #1^3 - 
      I wo^2 x^2 #1^3 - I wo^2 y^2 #1^3 - 2 I wo^2 z^2 #1^3 + 
      2 wo y #1^4 + I #1^5 &,2], {z, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]]];
```

I start to get different approximated roots. Could you please help me understand what is happening? The Series will be same in both cases but something is making it give me different results. Is there a problem with Series function, or is it because the roots have no closed form expressions?

Thank you.